# Is it possible to send a chat message without a recipient?

Tags: diablo-iii

Before patch 1.03 it used to be possible to send a chat message with no recipient by doing:

```
/p And then i type my message here
```

In other words, it was possible to send a message to your party, even when there was no one else in your party. As of 1.03 this is no longer possible. It yields the error message:

```
You can't do that command when not in-game. Type /? for more info.
```

Is it in any other way possible to send a chat message to no recipient? It sucks to have to spam friends or public chats with bogus messages...

Comment: If I've understood you correctly, you can't use /p at all?

Comment: @JamesJiao Ohh... I thought it was only because I was not in a game. But now that you said so, I joined a game and tried using `/p` and it still didn't work. So it seems `/p` is bugged... But is there any other way to send a message to nobody, so that I don't need to spam public chats or my friends?

Comment: I don't know if it works in Diablo III, but many chat systems let you message yourself. Also, why do you want to send a message with no recipient?

Comment: @Alderath If you type /?, do you see /p as an option? Or has something changed?

Comment: @Alderath As for the workaround, try closing the chat box and reopen it. See if that helps. Failing that, your only option is to /w the player. No other workaround I can think of that's not spammy.

Comment: @Alderath Also, try leaving the general chat. That *might* help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To send a message that nobody will see but yourself, simply leave all chat channels. An "invalid recipient" error message will display but your message is echoed back, allowing you to generate tooltips on items.

Before 1.0.3 I used to use /p while in the Auction House as a neat little trick to view the tooltip on something I sold (you can shift-click the icon for the gold in your completed tab).

Comment: How does this help with the OP's situation?

Comment: This was exactly the type of thing I was looking for. I've had general chat always opened, so I never noticed that this was possible.

Comment: @JamesJiao Exactly this was the reason for which I want to be able to send messages to no recipient: I want to be able to see the stats on items that I have sold on AH. The fact that an error message is generated doesn't bother me at all. As long as I can see what item I sold I'm happy. And previously I just spammed the items in private msgs to a friend or on some not very frequently visited channel, like witch doctor chat for example. It's better with this method, so that you don't have to bother others with your workarounds to display item stats.

Comment: I think I might've misunderstood Elbyron's solution. Maybe it's the way it's worded.

Comment: @Alderath: Why not just ask 'how do I view information on sold items' instead of asking how to continue a specific workaround?

Comment: @JamesJiao You're right, my solution wasn't worded very well, mainly because I was guessing at what Alderath was trying to accomplish. I've edited it to answer the question more directly.

Comment: @Alok Are you saying that there exists a better way of viewing info on sold items than posting item links in chat?

Comment: Idk, but its more obvious as to what you really want to ask (so if there *is* a better way, someone can post that.

Comment: @Alok There is already a question answering that. And the answer is basically "sold items can be posted to chat". The reason for which i phrased it this way is that some people here seem obsessive about closing down even remotely similar questions. I have seen several " after [some significant game mechanics change in a patch]  does it still apply that [something]" get closed by someone stating that its a copy of some other question with completely and utterly outdated answers.

Comment: @Alderath: Understand that viewpoint completely, and I did find this useful as I didn't know this trick to referencing items before selling.